# How do you show that the norm for square matrices is submultiplicative?

Tags: matrices, definition, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, matrix-norms

In these notes: http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat610/sum10/lecture2.pdf

It says that square matrices satisfy so called submultiplicative norm $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$. Is it by definition or is there some way to prove this?

Comment: BTW I have no idea where did you find this statement in the linked text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all norms that can be given to matrices have this property. However, there are a family of important matrix norms, called "induced norms" (also "operator norms"), which are defined by

$$\| A \| = \sup_{\| x \| = 1} \| A x \|$$

for some vector norm $\| \cdot \|$. Such norms are indeed submultiplicative, because if $\| x \| = 1$ then $\| AB x \| \leq \| A \| \| Bx \| \leq \| A \| \| B \| \| x \| = \| A \| \| B \|$.

Comment: Sorry but why does the inequality hold for square matrices but not other types of matrices?

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant Well, if $A$ and $B$ are not square and can be multiplied, then they aren't in the same space, which means that $\| A \|$ and $\| B \|$ are really not the same norm (since these two norms act on different spaces).

Answer (score 0):

It is not always the case. There are matrix norms that do not have this property. That depends on that definition of the matrix norm we are using, since there are many. To name a few:

1) Operator norm (induced norms)

2) Frobenius norm

3) P norm